# New Google Sites and new domain/URL

Tags: google, domains, godaddy, google-sites

I migrated an old site to the New Google Sites. Rather than having a long URL `https://sites.google.com/site/mywebsite`, I would like to have a short one, like `https://mycompany.com`. So I bought the domain on GoDaddy, and added a redirection, which works. However, the redirection does not mask the old URL, which is still visible in the browser.

I found these [instructions on Google Help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7392423?hl=en) to do it, but it seems that it applies only to business accounts. Is it possible to do it without a G Suite account?

Comment: No... it's not possible. Google Sites is not a proper hosting platform either.

Comment: If you are looking for free hosting, you might want to look at GitHub Pages or Netlify

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to have the same template on a proper host? Google Sites really match my needs in terms of design.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, New Google Sites supports custom domains for private Google accounts. It was added gradually through 2018. Read more on the [support pages](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/9068867?hl=en).

For my club site it works very well, with automatic SSL certificate and so, except one thing: "og:url" still points to the "sites" URL so sharing on Facebook doesn't use my custom URL. I don't want people to even know that the URL `https://sites.google.com/view/sitename/` exists ...

PS! AFAIK `https://sites.google.com/site/mywebsite` is the URL format for the old Google Sites, but I guess you posted it just as an example of a long URL ...