# Unable to set up a domain in Google Domains pointing to a Google Site

Tags: google-workspace, google-sites, google-domains

I'm at my wits' end with this.

I'm trying to do something simple, that is direct a domain (something.org) rented at Google Domains to a site made in Google Sites. I am an Owner of both the domain and the site, and we use G Suite/Google Workspace. I am an Admin in said Workspace.

Supposedly, all I had to do was go to Google Domains, click on something.org, "Build website", then follow the steps to use Google Sites, "Use Existing Site." However, doing that gets me a cryptic error message saying `This site and domain require a Google Workspace admin to make the connection manually in the admin console.`

After reading through many tutorials that kept telling me to do the above, I eventually land at the Google Workspace Admin site, and try to add a Custom URL there. Except on step #3, I only have my organization's domain available to choose from (organization.org), I don't have something.org available.

If I go to Webmaster Central, I get a list of the 20-odd domains we have registered, and they all say that they're automatically verified.

In Google Sites, if I go to the site Settings, I don't have the "Custom URL" option available at all.

Alternatively, I tried setting up the DNS manually, but the problem is that in Google Sites I tried to site "something.org", only to be told that I can only use letters, numbers and dashes.

I've already read some 30 different tutorials and even videos, and I can't understand why none of this is working. Help! :)

Comment: Welcome to [webmasters.se]. I migrated the question from [webapps.se] becuase it's an edge question for that site. I suggest you to take the [tour], read [ask] and in case that you find that something was missing [edit] your question ASAP.

Comment: Related [How can I create a Google Site and use it with a Google Domain?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/99785/52555)

Comment: Another related [New Google Sites and new domain/URL](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/115559/52555)

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your Google Sites settings so we can see how it differs from the usual?  My setting have a custom domain setting.

Answer (score 1):

You might have missing some important details

Google Sites have two editions, Classic Sites and New Sites. Despite of how they be promoted, and that you bought the domain through Google Domains, the URL domain mapping procedure is not exactly the same. By the other hand:

> - In new Sites, you cannot map a site to a URL that's under a different domain name.

source: [Map a new URL to a site in Google Sites | Google Worspace Admin Help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7392423?hl=en)

The above means that in order to me able to map a site create in New Sites to something.org, that site

- should be owned by a Google consumer account (gmail.com)
- should be owned by a Google Workspace account from something.org

## Related

### Classic Sites

- [How can I create a Google Site and use it with a Google Domain?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/99785/52555)

### New Sites

- [New Google Sites and new domain/URL](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/115559/52555)